# Is NULL the same as False in C++

Tags: c++

In C++ (gcc,VS) is NULL considered the same as False. Or more importantly if in a logical statement what does NULL evaluate to. There were a number of other questions but none for C++ specifically.

For some reason looping with a NULL control for(;;) just freezes up the program indicating that there is something other than a NULL placed between the ;;. Note this code is something our professor believes to contain NULL values.

Comment: what does "looping with a NULL control for(;;)" mean? The loop `for(;;)` will loop forever, `for(;NULL;)` should never execute its body. Post real code.

Comment: Testing pointers using `if (!pointer) { }` works when a pointer is NULL, but not if it's an invalid address (such as 0xDEADBEEF).

Comment: for(;;) doesn't have any nulls in it.  Nothing isn't a null - null is null.  Am I missing something?

Comment: the code comes from a compsci professor to asking if a NULL is considered true, but testing the code and based on these responses the code does not contain NULLs as he expects. In any case what is between the for(;;) that makes the statement true?

Comment: Could you show us some of the code?  A `for` statement is neither true nor false.  The second clause (between the semicolons) is a condition, and the loop body will execute as long as that clause is true (it's tested before each execution).

Answer (score 28):

I believe NULL is generally defined to be 0, which coincidentally evaluates to false when used as a boolean expression.

Comment: And anything that is not 0, evaluated to true

Comment: Kinda sorta ... the precompiler substitutes the four characters NULL with the single character 0.  If this results in code that compiles as the integer 0, then what you say is correct.

Comment: John, it seems like you're splitting hairs. What distinction are you trying to make?

Comment: He's wrong anyway: `1NULL1` isn't `101`. The preprocessor replaces the __token__ `NULL` with the token `0`.

Comment: @Arve a stream in an invalid state is not 0, but evaluates to false, as can anything which overloads operator bool.

Comment: Pete, Arve obviously meant that any *integer or pointer* that isn't zero evaluates as true. A stream object is neither.

Comment: It isn't coincidental.  The null pointer value is supposed to evaluate to false, and so is integer 0.  All other pointer and integer values are supposed to evaluate to true.

Comment: You are both wrong, folks. It can also be `0L` (long) or any other zero constant integer value. If you split hairs, then please split them *really* :)

Answer (score 7):

In C++, `NULL` is `#defined` to 0 (and thus evaluates to false). In C, it is a `void*`, which also evaluates to false, but its type is not a numeric type. In the standard library (at least on GCC):

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
```

Comment: In C it *could be* a `void *`, but not necessarily *is* a `void *`. It could easily be defined as `0` in C as well, just like in C++.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're considering the following code:

```
for (;;) { }
```

That will loop forever because the condition term is empty. You might be tempted to refer to that as *the null condition* to indicate that there is no condition present, but as you and everyone else who has read your question can attest, it's a confusing phrase to use because it does *not* mean the same as this:

```
for ( ; NULL; ) { }
```

The above won't loop at all. It uses the macro `NULL`, which is equivalent to the integer constant zero, and zero in a Boolean context is treated as false. That's not "the null condition" because there *is* a condition there — a condition that is always false.

If you got this from your professor, and he is teaching a class in C++, then I suspect you misunderstood him, because this isn't something I'd expect a professor to get wrong, so go ask him to fill in the hole in your notes. If he's not a C++ professor, then maybe he simply tried to use a C++ example to illustrate some other topic. You might wish to send him a note about it so that he can clarify and present some different example in future lectures.

Answer (score 0):

NULL on gcc on some platforms (Mac) is much more complicated than that. It tries to start using the nullptr thingy from next cxx rev. Even so it should still evaluate to false in a boolean context

Comment: NULL is used to denote the null pointer constant, which evaluates to false in a boolean context.  It really doesn't matter how it's specifically defined.