# C if condition difference

Tags: c

While I was coding a program in C, I came up a question that I could not figure out. I was checking if a condition is met in an if statement but was wondering if there is any difference between the following:

```
if(ptr != NULL)
or
if(ptr)
```

To me, I feel like both of those are correct but in the C world, the second one would be used more and in the Java world, the first one is used more. Is one more correct then the other?

Comment: The first one is certainly clearer, although c veterans will recognize the second one for what it is.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/459743

Comment: They are both correct. And both convey different programming idioms.

Comment: In the java world, the second one is not valid, so naturally the preference would be the first form.

Answer (score 3):

In C, anything that evaluates to `0` (zero) is "false", and anything non-zero is "true".

Thus when `ptr` is `NULL`, those two `if` conditions end up working the same way:

`if (ptr != NULL)` = `if (0 != 0)` = `if (0)`

and:

`if (ptr)` = `if (0)`

You'll get people debating which is better, but you'll see both in code.  The first is more clear because it's more explicit.  The second is shorter.  Both are technically correct and equivalent.

Comment: NULL is not equal to 0 for all the time. there is some platform which NULL != 0

Comment: @MOHAMED - I've never heard of that.  What platforms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616177/is-null-false-in-c-and-c-anything-more-than-0x0-0b0-0-0  and http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: Interesting.  However, those links indicate that `NULL` evaluates to "an integer constant with the value 0", though the bitwise representation of such a value may not be 0x0 on some platforms.  I believe my answer is still correct and helpful since I'm not discussing the bitwise representation of the `if` conditions.

Comment: yes exactelly. even if the NULL is not 0 but for theses platforms NULL is evaluated to 0 so your answer is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and equivalent.

A pointer alone evaluates to `false` if the pointer is `NULL` and to `true` otherwise.