# What is the diffrrent between Bytecode Instruction that makes one language support premitive null check inside if flow control and the other not?

Tags: java, c++, bytecode

why c++ support this

```
int main()
{
  if(NULL)
    std::cout << "compile";  
  if(5)       
    std::cout << "compile";  
  if(4.78)
    std::cout << "compile";
  if("lala")
    std::cout << "compile";
}
```

and in java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(null) System.out.println("true");
    }
}
```

> Error:(5, 12) java: incompatible types:  cannot be converted
>   to boolean

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

[image]

java and c++ it's just an example
Lua and js also support this 
and kotlin not
I am trying to understand why one language support null check by default and the other doesn't?

Comment: This has nothing to do with bytecode, it is language design choice.

Comment: Because in [C++ NULL is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2053716/2970947) and 0 is false. In Java, `null` is of the NullType (in fact, it's the only thing that's of the NullType).

Comment: why does one car have 2 doors while others have 4? Java is just specified that way, why must be asked to the team that started Java

Comment: null is not a magical word, you must check how it is defined in your language. In C its just an alias for 0.

Comment: hi, Mat thanks for the quick response don't you think its a standard in programming that if one value pass to flow control that it isn't a boolean we chacking to see if it isn't null?

Comment: No, it is not a standard in all languages (too much of them do not have a `null`) - and in Java it is considered an error having the wrong type is some places

Comment: That would be horrible. If you write `int i = 0;`, followed by `if(i) …` in C fashion it would imply `false` because zero, but if you write `Integer i = 0;`, followed by `if(i) …`, it would imply `true`, because non-`null`. It’s not as if Java was free of problems in this regard, but there are other language (like JavaScript), demonstrating [what happens, if you have too many implicit conversions](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascipt+comparison+madness)…

Comment: Great example Holger thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are different languages, and different languages can have different semantics! In C or C++, `NULL` actually just is a pre-processor macro, either defined to `0` or to an expression that produces a null pointer (`((void*)0)`). Additionally, C++ (but not C!) comes with a null pointer keyword (`nullptr`, since C++11) which nowadays should be preferred over the macro or the integer literal `0`.

Then in C and in C++, you can test numbers (integral or floating point) and pointers directly. Anything that compares equal to 0 is accepted as `false`, anything else is accepted as `true`. For instance:

```
int n = 0;
int* p = nullptr; // C++ only, 0 or NULL in C
double d = 0.0;

if(n) { }
if(p) { }
if(d) { }
// all of these are equivalent to if(x != 0), x being n, p or d
```

Alike, you can test literals as well (all below actually never enter the if branch):

```
if(false) { }
if(0) { }
if(nullptr) { }
```

Java, in contrast, *only* accepts true boolean values. So what is implicit in C or C++ must be written explicitly in Java (and possibly Lua, but I'm not familiar with):

```
if(someBoolean) { }        // fine, as boolean already
if(someInt != 0) { }
if(someReference != null) { }
```

Side note: There are yet some other languages that use C/C++ semantics as well, for instance Python or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, any numeric value will be coerced to boolean, with `0` being `false` and anything else being `true`, and `null` is a `0` value.

In Java, nothing coerces to boolean, it's a compile-time error if the value is not a `boolean` or `Boolean`.

Because that's the way the languages were designed.